# Char* created using malloc in function, compiler says address is on the stack and cannot be returned

Tags: c

I am writing a function that is supposed to take a string as input and add quotes around the word and then return the pointer to the new modified string.

```
//add quotes around a single word
char** _add_quotes(char* word){
        int char_count = 0;
        while(word[char_count] != '\0'){
                char_count++;
        }
        char* word_quotes = malloc((char_count+3) * sizeof(*word_quotes));
        word_quotes[0] = '\"';
        for(int i =0; i < char_count; i++){
                word_quotes[i+1] = word[i];
        }
        word_quotes[char_count+1] = '\"';
        word_quotes[char_count + 2] = '\0';
        return (&word_quotes);
}
```

This is where it returns

```
char** new_word_w_qs = _add_quotes(new_word); //add quotes
//copy new word with quotes to the final string
for (int m = 0; m < word_len; m++){
new_string[string_index] = *new_word_w_qs[m];
string_index++;
}
```

I expected it to return the address of the string on the heap, instead I got an error.
warning: address of stack memory associated with local variable 'word_quotes' returned [-Wreturn-stack-address]
        return (&word_quotes);
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: BTW, have you ever heard of `strlen()` and `strcpy()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char f() {
    char a = 'a';
    return &a;
}
```

The variable `a` stops existing after the function returns. So after the function returns, the variable `a` does not exists, the address of the variable `&a` is invalid after the function returns, there is no memory there after the function returns.

```
char **f2() {
   char *b = "abc";
   return &b;
}
```

This is the same. The `b` variable does not exists after the function, so the address of the `b` variable is invalid after the function returns. No matter if it's a pointer. The address stored inside `b` variable is still valid, but the address of variable `b` is invalid after the function returns.

Just return the pointer by value, not a pointer to the pointer.

```
//add quotes around a single word
char* _add_quotes(char* word){
        ...
        char* word_quotes = malloc((char_count+3) * sizeof(*word_quotes));
        ...
        // this is the value as returned by malloc()
        // the pointer value returned by malloc still valid after the function returns 
        return word_quotes;
}
```

And your function could be rewritten to use standard library functions:

```
char* _add_quotes(char* word){
        char* word_quotes = calloc((strlen(word) + 3), sizeof(*word_quotes));
        if (word_quotes == NULL) return NULL;
        strcat(word_quotes, "\"");
        strcat(word_quotes, word);
        strcat(word_quotes, "\"");
        return word_quotes;
}
```

or even:

```
char* _add_quotes(char* word){
        char* word_quotes = calloc((strlen(word) + 3), sizeof(*word_quotes));
        if (word_quotes == NULL) return NULL;
        sprintf(word_quotes, "\"%s\"", word);
        return word_quotes;
}
```

Comment: I edited my post to show what I do with the returned value. I thought it meant I needed to return a char** and that I wouldn't be able to dynamically return a string. Do you still think I should just return a char*?

Comment: You can return a char**, but then you have to allocate memory for it. Like `char **ret = malloc(sizeof(*ret)); *ret = word_quotes; return ret;`. Grab a paper and try to draw where the pointers point to. `word_quotes` is already a pointer to a string, there is no point in returning a pointer to a pointer to a string. Also, your new code is (very) invalid, the `*new_word_w_qs[m];` is grouped as `*(new_word_w_qs[m]);` - so first `new_word_w_qs` is incremented by `m` and derefernced then it is derefernced. You want `(*new_word_w_qs)[m]` first get the value of double pointer, then get `m` character

Comment: Why calloc instead of malloc?

Comment: Just want to save myself from typing `word_quotes[0] = '\0'` before calling `strcat`. However, I could use `malloc` with `strcpy(word_quotes, "\"");` in the first code snipped. In the second one it makes no difference. Just a habit when I'm working with strings, I guess.

Comment: does sprintf add a '\0' to the end? I had length of word + 3 because I was adding '\0' but you don't have that.

Comment: Yes, it does, always. The `+3` part is very good. The `sprintf` doesn't check for buffer overflow, so maybe using `sprintf(word_quotes, strlen(word) + 3, ...` would be "safer" (the "safer" means: if another developer starts changing your code, it won't brake that fast (well, both the developer and the code)).